# Razor Syntax in MVC with VB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, syntax

In my view, there is a Model that holds a list of `User` objects. I save the profile pictures of these users in `~/thumbs` folder as `<username>.png`. Now, I want to display all users with their profile pictures and name. So I've wrote the code as shown below

```
@Code
    For Each item in Model
        @<div class="col-md-2">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="~/thumbs/@item.username.png" alt="">
        </div>
    Next
End Code
```

Here, **@item.username.png** generates an error because the intellisense of Visual Studio assumes that I want to display the `png` property of the `username` of the `@item`

If I put a space before `.png` and write the `src` attribute as `~/thumbs/@item.username .png` the error gets resolved, but when I run the page; it doesn't show the images since ultimately the `src` is converted to `thumbs/<username>%20.png`

What can I do? Please advise!

Comment: can you preformat that string?

Comment: I am new to ASP.NET MVC, so I don't know how to preformat a string. Any link that explains the same will be appreciated! If I implement the same in Web Forms using Repeater, I'll use `Eval()` function that allows me to format strings. Are you talking about some similar option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following to avoid compile razor syntax problem

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="~/thumbs/@(item.username).png" alt="">
```

refer [here quick - reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, as per Daniel's comment, you'll can also pre-format the string, or build the string inline, e.g. with `String.Format`:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="@String.Format("~/thumbs/{0}.png", item.username)" alt="">
```